# PySpark working on colab without installations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I am working with Spark on Google Colab. However, when I instantiate a SparkSession:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("word count").getOrCreate()
```

it works normally even though I did not install Spark nor did I set the environment variables.

Therefore, even when I do **not** add the below block of code, it works normally.

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.0.1/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz  #install Apache Spark
!tar xf spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
import os 
os.environ['JAVA_HOME']='/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64'
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']='/content/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7'
```

Does anyone have a reason for that?

Comment: maybe you already executed the installs once, so you don't need make it again, unless you reset the environment.

Comment: @RafaelDouradoD Yes I did that but in another notebook

Answer (score 0):

As said by @RAfaelDourado

> maybe you already executed the installs once, so you don't need make it again, unless you reset the environment.